# PCR primer design for specific region

Tags: pcr, primer

I want to amplify a specific region of my genome. I want the segment to be as precise as possible but the primers that would align to the start and end of the target fragment are not optimal in terms of qualities checked for primer design (GC content, melting temperature, etc).

Is there a way to amplify a specific segment of the genome as precisely as I want in this instance? Are there some tricks that one can use when primer pairs are not optimal?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the first 50 bases of the start and last 50 bases of the end? I find it hard to believe there is no primer length available you can use.

Comment: have you looked into primer design tools like [primer3](https://primer3.ut.ee/)?